# Is all the nonelementary function that is not piecewise could be express as infinite series of elemetary function?

Tags: analysis

Are all the non-elementary functions that is not piecewise expressible as an infinite series of elementary functions?

details about elementary function - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function

Comment: Every *analytic* function is is locally expressable as a power series. Every *periodic* function can be expressed as a Fourier series (except at discontinuities, where they might disagree).

Comment: If you're willing to take 'locally a power series' then the answer is yes by Fourier series.